# MongoDB being held for ransom

Tags: mongodb, security

My mongodb is now held for ransom with a message of "Your DB is Backed up at our servers, to restore send 0.1 BTC to the Bitcoin Address then send an email with your server ip". After reading many articles, I am still unsure what publicly accessible database mean. Currently I access my database by SSH into my droplet with username and password and connect via port 27017 how can hacker access my db? Please advise me on what to do to prevent this happening in the future! Thank you

Comment: I got hit with the same one today. Luckily I keep regular backups but I am also interested in preventing this from happening again. the email it gives is `kraken0@india.com` which seems to be a popular ransomware email scam, but I can't find any resources about it targeting VPS.

I am also with DigitalOcean, connecting via SSH.

Comment: Hi! Exactly the same email! I am reading more now. It seems that you publicly exposed your database. So the hacker can just log into you database via you ip + correct port without any form of authentication!

Comment: Yeah, @0xDUDE on Twitter has been rounding them up for a bit

Comment: Hi do you mind telling me what backup method you use? I have snapshot back up 7 days ago. Do you use digital ocean snapshot backup?

Comment: Well I'm sure any professional would shoot me over this but I just use mongodump and mongorestore, dumping whenever I've made a sizeable change and I can copy it back to my local computer using git. User actions don't have a lasting impact on the database so it works for me, for now

Comment: thanks that is what I am doing too! But I am not very frequent on mongoddump and mongorestore. I am planning on writing a script to do this and link to my dropbox or something.. Sounds really unprofessional lol!

Comment: Same thing occured to me also. I dont have backup. Is there any way to get the backup?

Comment: @user123 unfortunately no : ( If you get hit, they probably delete your database. Because they can do anything to public database!

Comment: Who are they? They say "Your DB is Backed up at our servers, to restore send 0.1 BTC to the Bitcoin Address then send an email with your server ip". Will this help/

Comment: Hi, it might be a scam, your database might not even be with them right now. It also might not, some ransomware gives back what they took. So it is up to you whether you want to take the risk of paying or not : (

Answer (score 2):

To prevent this type of hacking you need make your database secure..

**Add the security.authorization setting to the config file**

```
security:
 authorization: enabled
```

Before enable it, make sure you have created root user with credential to login.

Example:

```
$ use admin
$ db.createUser(
  {
    user: "superAdmin",
    pwd: "mySecurePassword",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  })
```

also you may need to create app separate users for each database with limited access, for more info, I have written one blog here [MongoDB enable authentication](https://medium.com/@raj_adroit/mongodb-enable-authentication-enable-access-control-e8a75a26d332#.tyo4f8pht).

for more info refer [MongoDB security best practices](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-security-best-practices) and [MongoDB security checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/?_ga=1.14)

Comment: Thank you for the write up! I just made my database secure yesterday. It is important to run MongoDB on non-standard port of 27017 for extra security. And in order to use the config file, we must make sure to run "mongod --config <path to config>" because "mongod" alone doesnt utilize to configuration file for some reason!